# Posting XML wrapped in SOAP posted using Curl results in invalid XML character was found exceptions

Tags: unicode, curl, xml, post

Sending an XML file using curl results in:

```
Invalid XML character (Unicode : 0x<integer>)
```

**Attempt to solve the issue**

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5743262) the issue will be solved if the XML version is changed to 1.1.

Although the version that resides in the XML file has been updated:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

curl seems to keep sending the XML as version 1.0.

**Second attempt to solve the issue**

Another attempt was changing the header that is used while posting using curl as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8; version=1.1"
```

Curl seems to ignore this as the output indicates that xml version 1.0 is used:

```
* Closing connection #0
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope
```

**Third attempt to solve the issue**

@Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 advised to create a small XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
    soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">
    <soap:Body>
        <note>
            <to>Test</to>
        </note>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

validate the syntax and subsequently post it:

```
An invalid XML character (Unicode : 0x<integer>) was found
```

**Fourth attempt to solve the issue**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5742563/2777965) the issue should not occur as `0x<integer_greater_than_20>` is greater than 0x20.

**Fifth attempt to solve the issue**

What does `0x<integer_greater_than_20>` represent? According to [this table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=0x) it represents Latin characters that seem to be acceptable.

**Sixth attempt to solve the issue**

Perhaps the XML file is invalid? No, according to Notepad++' Check XML syntax now option the XML is valid.

Comment: 0x61 is the letter "a", so it's valid in all versions so f XML. I think you may be barking up the wrong tree with XML version changes. Have you confirmed the XML isn't just invalid (bad/incomplete tag)?  If you create a new XML containing as little content as needed, will it upload OK?

Comment: If Notepad++ is (also) telling you the XML is invalid then that's most likely your problem, your XML is invalid.  Fix it so that it's valid XML and try again.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Sorry. I made a typo. Notepad++ indicates it is valid.

Comment: Sounds good.  Let us know how you make out (edit the actions and results into your existing question).